# How do I safely uninstall the many components of past SQL Server versions?

Tags: windows-10, uninstall, sql-server

I recently installed SQL Server 2017 Express on my Windows 10 operating system (PC). I also though have installations of 2016, 2012 and apparently 2008 as well from older installs. I'd like to uninstall all components that I don't need to run the latest version (they are taking up precious space on my HDD). The issues is two-fold. 1) Looking at the program list for uninstalls, there are many components from past versions I've installed as seen in the links below. 2) I don't know of a simple way to uninstall all together, just they are all installed together when downloaded from Microsoft. I'd like some advice on how to safely uninstall these without ruining my 2017 SQL Server Express setup. Thanks

[my old installs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tby0m.jpg)

[CLR types (have no clue what these are?)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecFFV.jpg)

Comment: Quick word of advice regardless before you start uninstalling, etc.... Be sure to have a good and valid full system backup just in case you hose it up you can recover your system.

Answer (score 0):

When uninstalling a software like “**any MS-SQL products and their dependencies**” from control panel, windows will tell you if this software is a dependency for your latest products or not. Thus, if it is not a dependency then you can uninstall them safely.
[Uninstalling SQL software from Control panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLhNb.jpg)

When uninstalling from control panel you will also need to make **startup type to automatic** for SQL products listed in **Services** section.
[making startup type to automatic in Services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRJcl.jpg)
Finally, you can use Microsoft **storage tool** to clean up your pc.
[using Storage tool to free up space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmYK7.jpg)